# If $a^2=a$ in an integral domain, then either $a=0$ or $a=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with zero element $0$ and unity element $1$. Suppose that $A$ is an element of $R$ for which $a^2=a$.
>
> Show that if $R$ is an integral domain, then either $a=0$ or $a=1$.

I have no idea where to start this problem.

Comment: Hint: $a^2-a=a(a-1)=0$

Comment: Do you know what is the definint property of *integral domains*?

Comment: R is An integral domain if for every a, b in R, if ab=0, then a=0 or b=0

Comment: Right. Now apply that to the above equality $\ a(a-1) = 0\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R$ is an integral domain, so:

$$(ab = 0 \Rightarrow a = 0 \lor b = 0), \forall a,b \in R$$

We have:

$$a^2 = a \Rightarrow a^2 - a = 0 \Rightarrow a(a-1)=0 \Rightarrow a = 0 \lor a - 1 = 0 \Rightarrow a = 0 \lor a = 1$$

Comment: This was really helpful!